# Received Z_BUF_ERROR while installing NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

#### I just received Z_BUF_ERROR while installing NativeScript. I did Google but without any luck.

Environment:

- Windows 10 Enterprise 1703 64-bit
- NodeJS v6.11.2
- npm  v5.3.0

Command:

- npm install -g nativescript

Error Log:

- 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
- 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
- 1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Hui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
- 1 verbose cli   'install',
- 1 verbose cli   '-g',
- 1 verbose cli   'nativescript' ]
- 2 info using npm@5.3.0
- 3 info using node@v6.11.2
- 4 verbose npm-session 4454628f9775be96
- 5 silly install loadCurrentTree
- 6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
- 7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nativescript 1244ms
- 8 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nativescript/-/nativescript-3.1.3.tgz 23ms (from cache)
- **9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for nativescript@latest unexpected end of file**
- **10 verbose stack Error: unexpected end of file**
- 10 verbose stack     at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17)
- 11 verbose cwd D:\Dev\Workspace\Local\Angular
- 12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
  13 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" - "C:\Users\Hui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "nativescript"
- 14 verbose node v6.11.2
- 15 verbose npm  v5.3.0
- **16 error code Z_BUF_ERROR**
- **17 error errno -5**
- **18 error unexpected end of file**
- 19 verbose exit [ -5, true ]

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Few suggestions - 1.) try to clean your npm cache (`npm cache clean`) and then retry the installation - you can also try to install a lower version of npm. 2.) Disable any antivirus before trying to install NativeScript. 3.) Post your actual error log

Comment: @Nick, thanks for your response. 
1) I just found this from npm official doc ''It should never be necessary to clear the cache for any reason other than reclaiming disk space, thus why clean now requires --force to run.". I am not sure I really need to do this.
My peer installed without such error by using Node JS 8.x.x, a higher version then mine. I also tried 8.x.x, same error.
2) I will try to disable the antivirus before installing.
3) This is the whole content I copied from the log file.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean cache by using this

```
npm cache clean --force
```